# TypeScript, React.ReactNode, withRouter, and connect

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, react-router-dom

**Update 2**
Based on [artem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54046437/typescript-react-reactnode-withrouter-and-connect#comment94929863_54046437)'s second comment, I was able to solve my issue by changing

```
component: <TestRoute />
```

to

```
component: TestRoute
```

**Update**
Based on [artem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54046437/typescript-react-reactnode-withrouter-and-connect#comment94928562_54046437)'s comment, I've modified my code to the following, and the error I was experiencing has gone away, but is replaced with a new one, this time in the constructor where I am assigning the component property to :

> ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/ts/components/app/StandardRouter.tsx:34:13
>       TS2322: Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass | FunctionComponent'.
>     Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent'.
>       Type 'Element' provides no match for the signature '(props: any, context?: any): ReactElement | null'.

StandardRouter.tsx

```
// React router component. Connects all routes to the application.
import * as React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Route, Switch, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'connected-react-router';
import { IntlProvider } from 'react-intl';
import _forEach from 'lodash/forEach';
import _find from 'lodash/find';
import { History, createHashHistory } from 'history';
import { connectRouter } from 'connected-react-router';
import reducerRegistry from '../../api/private/core/reducer-registry';
import routeRegistry from '../../api/private/core/route-registry';
import RouteObject from '../../interfaces/route-object';
import TestRoute from '../test/test-route';

class StandardRouter extends React.Component {
    constructor(props: object) {
        super(props);
        this._history = createHashHistory();
        reducerRegistry.register({
            name: 'router',
            key: 'cb3dceb0-367b-4c2a-a0fb-a8d8671283e2',
            reducer: connectRouter(this._history)
        });
        routeRegistry.setChangeListener(() => {
            if (this._isMounted) {
                this.forceUpdate();
            } else if (!this._isMounted && !this._doUpdate) {
                this._doUpdate = true;
            }
        });
        routeRegistry.register({
            key: '90e8246f-96a6-49a5-920a-a2cf0d347fcd',
            component: <TestRoute />, // <-- New error here
            paths: '/',
            text: 'Test 123'
        });
    }

    componentDidMount(): void {
        this._isMounted = true;
        if (this._doUpdate) {
            this.forceUpdate();
        }
    }

    private _history: History;
    private _isMounted: boolean = false;
    private _doUpdate: boolean = false;

    chooseRender(path: string, Comp: React.ComponentType): React.ReactNode {
        return <Comp />;
    }

    // Creates Route objects based on routes collection from registry
    renderPages(): React.ReactNode[] {
        const routes: React.ReactNode[] = [];
        const loadedRoutes: RouteObject[] = routeRegistry.getRoutes();
        _forEach(loadedRoutes, page => {
            const Component = withRouter(
                connect<any, any, any>(() => ({
                    pageid: page.pageId
                }))(page.component) // <-- Error on this line, on page.component.
            );
            if (Array.isArray(page.paths)) {
                // Multiple paths available for a single route. For example "/" and "/Home" for the
                // home page.
                _forEach(page.paths, inner => {
                    routes.push(<Route key={inner} path={inner} render={() => this.chooseRender(inner, Component)} />);
                });
            } else {
                // A single path for a route.
                routes.push(
                    <Route
                        key={page.paths}
                        path={page.paths}
                        render={() => this.chooseRender(page.paths as string, Component)}
                    />
                );
            }
        });
        return routes;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{ zIndex: -1 }}>
                <IntlProvider locale="en">
                    <div>
                        <ConnectedRouter history={this._history}>
                            <Switch>{this.renderPages()}</Switch>
                        </ConnectedRouter>
                    </div>
                </IntlProvider>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default StandardRouter;
```

route-object.ts

```
type RouteObject = {
    key: string;
    component: React.ComponentType<any>;
    paths: string | string[];
    text: string;
    shortText?: string;
    index?: number;
    pageId?: string;
    icon?: React.ReactNode;
};

export default RouteObject;
```

test-route.tsx

```
import React from 'react';

class TestRoute extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
        return <div />;
    }
}

export default TestRoute;
```

Again, I'm unsure why I'm unable to assign , which is a PureComponent, to a property of ComponentType. Thanks in advance!

Original Question Below

---

I am working to convert our javascript application to TypeScript, and am running into an issue. I'm still trying to grasp all of the TypeScript complexities.

We are dynamically wiring our our routes to redux and the router at run time. This is working correctly when in javascript, but since I've converted it to TypeScript, I'm having trouble getting it to compile. The error I'm getting is

> ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/ts/components/app/StandardRouter.tsx:63:21
>       TS2345: Argument of type 'ReactNode' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType'.
>     Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType'.

I can see that the error is caused by an invalid type, but I'm unsure why.

StandardRouter.tsx

```
// React router component. Connects all routes to the application.
import * as React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Route, Switch, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'connected-react-router';
import { IntlProvider } from 'react-intl';
import _forEach from 'lodash/forEach';
import _find from 'lodash/find';
import { History, createHashHistory } from 'history';
import { connectRouter } from 'connected-react-router';
import reducerRegistry from '../../api/private/core/reducer-registry';
import routeRegistry from '../../api/private/core/route-registry';
import RouteObject from '../../interfaces/route-object';
import TestRoute from '../test/test-route';

class StandardRouter extends React.Component {
    constructor(props: object) {
        super(props);
        this._history = createHashHistory();
        reducerRegistry.register({
            name: 'router',
            key: 'cb3dceb0-367b-4c2a-a0fb-a8d8671283e2',
            reducer: connectRouter(this._history)
        });
        routeRegistry.setChangeListener(() => {
            if (this._isMounted) {
                this.forceUpdate();
            } else if (!this._isMounted && !this._doUpdate) {
                this._doUpdate = true;
            }
        });
        routeRegistry.register({
            key: '90e8246f-96a6-49a5-920a-a2cf0d347fcd',
            component: <TestRoute />,
            paths: '/',
            text: 'Test 123'
        });
    }

    componentDidMount(): void {
        this._isMounted = true;
        if (this._doUpdate) {
            this.forceUpdate();
        }
    }

    private _history: History;
    private _isMounted: boolean = false;
    private _doUpdate: boolean = false;

    chooseRender(path: string, Comp: React.ComponentType): React.ReactNode {
        return <Comp />;
    }

    // Creates Route objects based on routes collection from registry
    renderPages(): React.ReactNode[] {
        const routes: React.ReactNode[] = [];
        const loadedRoutes: RouteObject[] = routeRegistry.getRoutes();
        _forEach(loadedRoutes, page => {
            const Component = withRouter(
                connect(() => ({
                    pageid: page.pageId
                }))(page.component) // <-- Error on this line, on page.component.
            );
            if (Array.isArray(page.paths)) {
                // Multiple paths available for a single route. For example "/" and "/Home" for the
                // home page.
                _forEach(page.paths, inner => {
                    routes.push(<Route key={inner} path={inner} render={() => this.chooseRender(inner, Component)} />);
                });
            } else {
                // A single path for a route.
                routes.push(
                    <Route
                        key={page.paths}
                        path={page.paths}
                        render={() => this.chooseRender(page.paths as string, Component)}
                    />
                );
            }
        });
        return routes;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{ zIndex: -1 }}>
                <IntlProvider locale="en">
                    <div>
                        <ConnectedRouter history={this._history}>
                            <Switch>{this.renderPages()}</Switch>
                        </ConnectedRouter>
                    </div>
                </IntlProvider>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default StandardRouter;
```

route-object.ts

```
type RouteObject = {
    key: string;
    component: React.ReactNode;
    paths: string | string[];
    text: string;
    shortText?: string;
    index?: number;
    pageId?: string;
    icon?: React.ReactNode;
};

export default RouteObject;
```

test-route.tsx

```
import React from 'react';

class TestRoute extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
        return <div />;
    }
}

export default TestRoute;
```

Is there anything that is sticking out that would cause this? I'm unsure why it's not taking a ReactNode.

Comment: `connect()(...)` is not applicable to [`ReactNode`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L172), `ReactNode` is too broad. From what I remember, `connect()` expects [`ComponentType`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L58) as the last argument.

Comment: @artem thanks for the information! I've updated my code and made another little tweak to the connect call, and that error is no longer occurring, however I'm now having an error where the property value does not like <TestRoute />, which is a pure component. I've updated the question with the new code and information.

Comment: `<TestRoute />` appearing by itself is not a component, it's rendered element according to TypeScript rules. I think it should be either `component: TestRoute` or  perhaps `component: () => <TestRoute />` .

Comment: @artem Gotcha, now I understand. Thank you so much, changing to simply TestRoute solved my problem and everything is working!